# Trying to connect to Boto3 Client from AWS Lambda and Receiving Timeout

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

My AWS Lambda function code works fine when I run it outside of an Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC). However, when I configure my function to connect to a VPC, I get function timeout errors. How do I fix these?

```
def get_db_connection_config():
    # Create a Secrets Manager client.
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )

    # In this sample we only handle the specific exceptions for the 'GetSecretValue' API.
    # See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
    # We rethrow the exception by default.

    try:
        logger.info("Retrieving MySQL database configuration...")
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )

    except ClientError as error:
        logger.error(error)
        sys.exit()

    else:
        # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
        # Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
            return json.loads(secret)
        else:
            return base64.b64decode(get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a Lambda resides in AWS network it is able to use the internet to connect to these services, however once it joins your VPC outbound internet traffic is also routed through your VPC. As there is presumably no outbound internet connectivity the Lambda is unable to reach the internet.

> If your function needs internet access, use network address translation (NAT). Connecting a function to a public subnet doesn't give it internet access or a public IP address.

For your Lambda to be able to communicate with other AWS services when it resides within a VPC, one of the following must be in place.

The first option is that you create either a [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) or a [NAT instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html), and then add this to the [route table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html) which your Lambda resides in. To be clear this subnet should be a private subnet only as by utilizing a NAT for a `0.0.0.0/0` record it will stop inbound traffic to instances which have a public IP address that share the same subnet.

The second option is that you utilize [VPC endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) for the services, by doing this any traffic that would have previously traversed the public internet will instead use a private connection directly to the AWS service itself. Please note that not every AWS service is covered yet for this.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me.
Before I had tried placing a lambda on a public subnet (0.0.0.0/0 -> igw + auto-assign public ip) and the lambda still could not fetch from secrets manager (timed out). Would you know why? I was thinking it could be that the subnet can't auto-assign a public ip to lambdas.

Comment: Kinda old question but to add my 2c, yes, that's exactly what I have seen in my experience. As soon as I place a Lambda function inside a VPC the function can't get a public IP unless you jump to the hoops previously described (set the Lambda in a private subnet and route all traffic to the NAT) Also remember to grant all of this to your execution role:
* "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface"
* "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces"
* "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
* "ec2:AssignPrivateIpAddresses"
* "ec2:UnassignPrivateIpAddresses"